# relationship between \x and unicode codepoints

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, hex, escaping

In Python (either 2 or 3), evaluating `b'\xe2\x80\x8f'.decode("utf-8")`

yields `\u200f`, and similarly `'\u200f'.encode("utf-8")` yields `b'\xe2\x80\x8f'`.

The first looks like a chain of three 2-character hex values that would equal decimal 226, 128, and 143. The second looks like a single hex value that would equal decimal 8,207.

Is there a logical relationship between '\xe2\x80\x8f' and '\u200f' ? Am I interpreting the values incorrectly?

I can see the values are linked somehow in tables like this one: https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128&utf8=string-literal

but why are these two values on the same row?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is related to the amount of bits/bytes that each character takes up to represent in utf-8.

> For any character equal to or below 127 (hex 0x7F), the UTF-8
>   representation is one byte. It is just the lowest 7 bits of the full
>   unicode value. This is also the same as the ASCII value.
>
> For characters equal to or below 2047 (hex 0x07FF), the UTF-8
>   representation is spread across two bytes. The first byte will have
>   the two high bits set and the third bit clear (i.e. 0xC2 to 0xDF). The
>   second byte will have the top bit set and the second bit clear (i.e.
>   0x80 to 0xBF).

There is more information about this [here](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/utf8.htm).

If you wanted more info on how Python uses these values, [check out here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the first is "a chain of three 2-character hex values that would equal decimal 226, 128, and 143." It's a byte string. You got a byte string because that's what `encode` does. You passed it UTF-8 so the bytes are the UTF-8 encoding for the input character string.

"The second looks like a single hex value that would equal decimal 8,207." Sort of; It's the notation for a UTF-16 code unit inside a literal character string. One or two UTF-16 code units encode a Unicode codepoint. In this case, only one is used for the corresponding codepoint.

Sure, you can convert the hex to decimal but that's not very common or useful in either case. A code unit is a specific bit pattern. Bytes are that bit pattern as an integer, serialized to a byte sequence.

The [Unicode](https://unicode.org) codepoint range needs 21 bits. UTF-16 encodes a codepoint in one or two 16-bit code units (so that's two bytes in some byte order for each code unit). UTF-8 encodes a codepoint in one, two, three or four 8-bit code units. (An 8-bit integer is one byte so byte order is moot.) Each character encoding has a separate algorithm to distribute the 21 bits into as many bytes are needed. Both are reversible and fully support the Unicode character set. So, you *could* directly convert one to the other.

The table you reference doesn't show UTF-16. It shows Unicode codepoint hex notation: U+200F. That notation is for humans to identify codepoints. It so happens that when UTF-16 encodes a codepoint in one code unit, it's number is the same as the codepoint's number.